# How can I make the width/height of particles randomly?

Tags: particles

I know, how to control and randomize the size, position and color of the particles in a ParticleSystem:

[image: Example]

But is it possible to randomize the width and height of the particles too, so that there are rectangles that have different sizes in this example?

Comment: I suggest you to look into animation-nodes. When it's about scattering objects, this addon will give you a lot more control and freedom!

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can have the different height and width of[image] each other. By using Random Size.

Comment: I want to get rectangles too and what you've shown does only change the height and width together and it doesn't make only the width or only the height smaller, so that it isn't a square anymore.